# Нужны ли кавычки в названии исправительно-трудовых лагерей?

Tags: ономастика, кавычки

Например: Дмитровлаг, Норильлаг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что кавычки не нужны.

> **Примечание.** Не выделяются кавычками:
> б) названия предприятий, учреждений, издательств, управлений и т. д., представляющие собой сложносокращенное слово, образованное из полного официального наименования, например: *Днепрогэс, Автоваз, Гидропроект*...

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Тем временем незадачливого путешественника перебросят куда-нибудь на Ухту, в Вишеру, в **Дальлаг**... (И. Л. Солоневич. Россия в концлагере [**1935**]);

Но уже в 50-м году Кто-то нашел удобным стягивать женщин не в **Озерлаге**, а в **Дубровлаге** ― в Темниках, в Мордовии (А. И. Солженицын. Архипелаг ГУЛаг [**1958–1973**]);

Поехал в **Дмитровлаг** под Москву, и там его устроил к себе домработником Дмитрий Павлович Каллистов (Д. С. Лихачев. Воспоминания [**1995**]);

Прожил отец Иоанн недолго, в 1946 году он скончался на поселении в низовьях Оби, куда после отсидки в **Озерлаге** (его пятый срок) были сосланы несколько десятков старообрядческих семей, образовавших в этих гиблых местах нечто вроде сельскохозяйственной коммуны (Владимир Шаров. Воскрешение Лазаря [**1997–2002**]).

[§129. Названия литературных, музыкальных произведений, средств массовой информации, предприятий, фирм, учебных заведений и т. д.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/54.htm)

Comment: Почему же вы тогда не написали полные названия?